# OpenLaszlo kills some mouse events of a loaded Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, openlaszlo

This is a question about OpenLaszlo (or rather Flex?) internals:

I was able to load a full Flex application swf into a OpenLaszlo (trunk release, older releases failed). It works in Flash 10 as well as in 11. But OpenLaszlo seems to capture or 
block certain mouse events. When I add the SWF into

```
YFilesSWF.content.sprite (YFilesSWF is extending the window class)
```

then most mouse actions work (e.g. Flex buttons), but some don't (some clickable items on a kindo f canvas). I observed further that when I add the SWF to

```
YFilesSWF.sprite (YFilesSWF is extending the view)
```

, then the SWF does not react to ANY mouse events anymore. That means window is somewhat better, but not good enough. 
I'm using the

```
flash.display.Loader
```

class for loading the SWF in a normal way. This is the AS3 Loader class implementation which I use for loading the swf and which I include **inside the OpenLaszlo app** :

```
 public class LoadSwf extends Sprite
 {
      public var externalSwfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
      public var swfDisplayObject:DisplayObject;
      public var swfComObject:Object;

     public function LoadSwf(url:String,p:Sprite):void
     {
//                externalSwfLoader.mouseChildren = false;
//                this.mouseChildren = false;
//                p.mouseChildren = false;   

//                externalSwfLoader.mouseEnabled = false;
//                this.mouseEnabled = false;
//                p.mouseEnabled = false;   

            p.addChild(this);
          externalSwfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, createSwfObjects);
          externalSwfLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
     }

     public function createSwfObjects(evt:Event):void
     {
          var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = evt.target as LoaderInfo;

          swfDisplayObject = evt.target.content;
          swfComObject = loaderInfo.content;

          addChild(swfDisplayObject);
     }
}
```

This is the OpenLaszlo code of how the class is used:

```
<class name="YFilesSWF" extends="window">

            <passthrough>
                    import LoadSwf;
            </passthrough>

            <attribute name="loadSwf" />

            <handler name="oninit"><![CDATA[
                    this.loadSwf = new LoadSwf("SimpleGraphEditor.swf", this.content.sprite);
            ]]></handler>
 </class>
```

Does anybody know what and where OpenLaszlo is destroying some
of the Flex mouse events and how to prevent it? 
Is there a yet better component than window that will
preserve the Flex mouse events?
What would be required to modify in the OL components source code?

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it by myself by simply extending view instead of window and then setting the defaultplacement attribute to null. The x coordinate is being set to 1254 for no reason, such that I keep it to 0 using a handler. But then everything works fine.

Comment: But the YFilesSWF class shall not be entirely empty, therefore adding a dummy view is required, like this:     <attribute name="defaultplacement" value="dummy"/>
                <view name="dummy">
                </view>